# Is there a way to make the ultimate responsive image?

Tags: jquery, html, css, image

I've been making sites and other online projects for several years, I started way back when EVERYTHING was done in tables. Over the years I've watched everything change, now I think the best websites are the ones that are actually responsive. However, there's always been a limitation for me, and maybe this has already been done, but I can't seem to find it.

What I would like to see possible is to have some code, even if it's JQuery, that essentially says something like:

```
img {
width: 100%;
max-width: **The ACTUAL image's width**;
}
```

Is there some magic code or trick to make the website make an image I post never break my design (the `width: 100%;` part, so it's also responsive), but if the image I'm uploading is smaller than the width of the container, to never exceed the actual width of the image itself. I know I could just set a specific width on the `max-width` to force images to resize, but that feels a little too.. hacky to me. The page I'm making currently is for wordpress and the user will sometimes just upload an image with the post, I would like for the image to be responsive, but only responsive in terms of shrinking, never growing. So, any of you super geniuses know of a way to accomplish this?

Thanks!

Comment: switch it around, just use `max-width: 100%` then if the container is smaller than the image it will respond, but if it is bigger than the image it wont

Comment: The image will never be bigger than the container. max-width doesn't tell the image to get the size of the container and resize upwards. For me, your question makes no sense. If the image is smaller than its container, it will fill its part. If it is bigger, it is going to resize downwards.

Comment: You're right, I just tested that specific theory and it works perfectly. Sorry, clearly I didn't research this enough.

Answer (score 1):

simply max-width it at 100% and leave out width

Comment: Would the down-voter care to comment?

Comment: i up voted this as it didn't deserved a down vote